# How to get VsCode code suggestions to work after I bind context to something else?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have this class:

```
class Cat {
  name = 'Mr. Kitten';
  /**
   * A list of names
   */
  namesList = ['Bob', 'Snow'];

  changeName() {
    this.name = this.getNameFromList();
  }
  getNameFromList() {
    return this.namesList[0];
  }
}
```

In this example, VsCode suggests things from the 'this' context just fine inside the `getNameFromList()` method. If I mouseover the `namesList` variable inside that method, then it shows my JSDocs comments for that variable. Shows me the Type of the variable. Everything is fine. But if I refactor this code to make `getNameFromList` a function inside `changeName`, like so:

```
class Cat {
  name = 'Mr. Kitten';
  /**
   * A list of names
   */
  namesList = ['Bob', 'Snow'];

  changeName() {
    this.name = getNameFromList.bind(this)();

    function getNameFromList() {
      return this.namesList[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Now VsCode no longer suggests anything for `this.namesList` inside `getNameFromList`, because `this` now refers to a different context and VsCode can't possibly know that I'll be binding `this` every time I call that function. Since I will always call that function with `.bind(this)`, then I would like VsCode to show suggestions from that context.

Is there any way to let VsCode knows that the `this` inside that one function will always be bound to some other context, so that I can get autocompletion and suggestions to work inside `getNameFromList` again?

Comment: You should use `.call(this)` instead of `.bind(this)()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the jsdoc [`this` annotation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-this.html) to explicitly state the type of `this`:

```js
class Cat {
  name = 'Mr. Kitten';
  /**
   * A list of names
   */
  namesList = ['Bob', 'Snow'];

  changeName() {
    this.name = getNameFromList.bind(this)();

    /** @this {Cat} */
    function getNameFromList() {
      return this.namesList[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why use jsdoc when the OP is using TypeScript?

Comment: It looked to me like they were using JS. Just to cover the TS case, you can specify the type of `this` by writing: `function getNameFromList(this: Cat) {  ... }`. And in both JS and TS, arrow functions avoid this problem entirely.